# Error installing scoop command line installer

Tags: powershell, scoop-installer

I am trying to install scoop in my Powershell but I'm getting an error which says:

`Invoke-RestMethod: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Also the Get-ExecutionPolicy returns RemoteSigned.

I tried using the command `irm get.scoop.sh | iex` which returned the error I also tried using the other commands like `iwr -useb get.scoop.sh | iex`

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod get.scoop.sh` works just fine for me on both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7. This is unlikely a PowerShell scripting issue but more likely a connection problem. What happens when you paste `get.scoop.sh` in your browser? Does it show the script?

Comment: no, it shows ```raw.githubusercontent.com took too long to respond.```

Comment: Ok, that means that you do not have a connection (and that this indeed not a PowerShell scripting issue).

Comment: I recommend to drop your connection issue at the [superuser](https://superuser.com/) site with more details about your computer environment.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I'll try doing that

Answer (score 1):

try this commands it's work for me :

1. [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
2. iwr -useb get.scoop.sh -outfile 'install.ps1'
3. .\install.ps1 -RunAsAdmin
4. scoop install symfony-cli

Answer (score 1):

iex "& {$(irm get.scoop.sh)} -RunAsAdmin"

this PowerShell command works fine

Answer (score 0):

**Step:1**
**Run the following command to install Scoop:**

```
iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
```

**Ste:2**
**Restart PowerShell**